# Regular Expression: Positive Lookahead Not Stopping At Specified Digit Range?

Tags: regex

I looked for similar questions but couldn't find exactly what I need. I have this string of data, as an example:

```
2016 12
2017 01
2017 02
2017 03
2017 04
2017 05
2017 06
2017 07
2017 12
2018 01
2018 02
2018 03
2018 04
2018 05
2018 06
2018 07
```

And I need to filter for just a select range, in this case 2017|05 through 2018|04. I'm using this regex:

```
((?=2017).*(?=0[5-9]|1[0-2]).*)|((?=2018).*(?=0[1-4]).*)
```

Which works fine for the 2017 range, but just continues to include 2018|05 and onward. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Try [`2017 (?:1[0-2]|0[5-9])|2018 0[1-4]`](https://regex101.com/r/m28QHi/1)

Comment: You should of use `(2017 (?=0[5-9]|1[0-2]).*)|(2018 (?=0[1-4]).*)`

Comment: Why are you using lookaheads for this? Just do normal matching.

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will match any within the *continuous* range of your dates.
*Note this doesn't force sequential (ascending) month/day, but must be sequential year, since it's a from - to thing.*

`(?:2017[ ](?:0[5-9]|1[0-2])\r?\n)+(?:2018[ ]0[1-4](?:\r?\n|$))+`

https://regex101.com/r/SDwLx0/1

Expanded

```
 (?:
      2017 [ ]                      # 2017
      (?: 0 [5-9] | 1 [0-2] )       # 05 - 12
      \r? \n 
 )+
 (?:
      2018 [ ]                      # 2018
      0 [1-4]                       # 01 - 04
      (?: \r? \n | $ )
 )+
```

---

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas why this might be happening?

The second half of your pattern `((?=2018).*(?=0[1-4]).*)` will match like this (using `_` to visualize spaces):

**For line `2018_01`:**
`(?=2018)` matches `2018`
`.*` matches `2018_`
`(?=0[1-4])` matches `01`
`.*` matches `01`

**For line `2018_05`:**
`(?=2018)` matches `2018`
`.*` matches `2`
`(?=0[1-4])` matches `01` *(middle two digits of 2018)*
`.*` matches `018_01`